# XSLT create empty document if match criteria is not met

Tags: xml, string, xslt, match, filtering

I would like to get an empty document if  does not match my criteria city and **also select some specific elements only. The requirement is to transform only some specific elements, and sub elements preferred only. Means that not all elements should be copied**

Here is my sample XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" TimeStamp="2020-06-20T16:15:01.9906696+07:00" Version="9.1" Sequence="827170" xmlns="http://localhost/2007/00">    
    <ID>001</ID>
    <Student>
        <Profile>
            <Name>G1</Name>
            <City>PNH</City>            
            <RegDate>2020-06-20</RegDate>
        </Profile>
        <Origin>
            <Address>
                <City>REP</City>
            </Address> 
        </Origin>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Profile>
            <Name>G4</Name>
            <City>REP</City>            
            <RegDate>2020-06-20</RegDate>
        </Profile>
        <Origin>
            <Address>
                <City>PNH</City>
            </Address> 
        </Origin>
    </Student>       
</Class>
```

And below is my xslt sample that I try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:ns0="http://localhost/2007/00">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns0:Student[not(ns0:Profile/ns0:City = 'PNH')]" />

<!--select Profile from student only -->
<xsl:template match="ns0:Student">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Profile"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- select City and RegDate from Profile only -->
      <xsl:template match="ns0:Profile">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:City|ns0:RegDate"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, I would like to find student where profile > city equals KOS
If no student found, I would like  the process to return empty string. But after running, it got `<Class>` and `<ID>` in the context not an empty string as expected.

Would you mind to assist how to get empty string as result if City does not match my criteria?

This is what I expected to see if the City is match my criteria (Student>Profile>City='PNH')

```
<Class xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://localhost/2007/00" TimeStamp="2020-06-20T16:15:01.9906696+07:00" Version="9.1" Sequence="827170">
 <ID>001</ID>
    <Student>
        <Profile>
            <City>PNH</City>            
            <RegDate>2020-06-20</RegDate>
        </Profile>
    </Student>
</Class>
```

If City is not match than only empty string return.

Comment: What should the exact result be when such student does exist?

Comment: I have updated my quested with expected result of when criteria City is meet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***--- edited in view of changes in question ---***

To meet the added  requirements, you will need to approach it differently:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://localhost/2007/00">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns0:Class">
    <xsl:variable name="stu" select="ns0:Student[ns0:Profile/ns0:City='KOS']" />
    <xsl:if test="$stu">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@* | ns0:ID"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$stu"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:Student">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Profile"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:Profile">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:City|ns0:RegDate"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It miss <ID> tag when condition is match

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: By doing this, I will get all element and sub elements. I have updated my question about other details require. I do not need to copy all elements, I need to get only some specific elements and sub elements only. It should remove those not meet in require elements and sub elements

Comment: [groan] How are we supposed to know that? I have made another change (which I believe you could have made yourself). I will not make another.

Comment: Thanks for your update, by the way, after run the test I got PNH2020-06-20 in series instead of <City>PNH</City> <RegDate>2020-06-20</RegDate> in the profile element, when I change city in variable stu to 'PNH'?

Comment: That is not the result I see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUk

Comment: When I try to add an additional element to the XML source  inside <Student> with <SpecialAction>Insert</SpecialAction> and also add condition in <xsl:template match="ns0:Student"> with <xsl:apply-templates select="ns0:Profile|ns0:SpecialAction|ns0:Origin"/> I got result incorrect. It remove tag SpecialAction by keeping only text as shown in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUk/1

Comment: You do not have a template that would process `ns0:SpecialAction`.